# How do I add only cpp file in GitHub using ‚git add‘

Tags: github

I have various types of files in a folder and would like to upload only the '.cpp' files to my GitHub repository.
How can I selectively add specific files, in this case '.cpp' files, to a GitHub repository using the `git add` command?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `git add **/*.cpp`. That command will select all the files with that extension in folders and subfolders.